# Non-fully qualified frame_id

Tags: ros, laser-geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,
I am trying to convert an incoming laser scan from a hokuyo urg laser scanner into a pointcloud for the purpose of building a octomap. Here is the code I'm working with, which is mostly from a tutorial:

```
class LaserScanToPointCloud {
  public:
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector;
    tf::TransformListener listener;
    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> laser_sub;
    tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> laser_notifier;
    ros::Publisher scan_pub;

    LaserScanToPointCloud(ros::NodeHandle n): node(n), laser_sub(node, "scan", 10),
    laser_notifier(laser_sub, listener, "Brain5", 10) {
      laser_notifier.registerCallback(boost::bind(&LaserScanToPointCloud::scanCallback, this, _1));
      laser_notifier.setTolerance(ros::Duration(.01));
      scan_pub = node.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("my_cloud", 1);
    }

    void scanCallback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_in) {
      sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
      try {
        projector.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("Brain5", *scan_in, cloud, listener);
      }
      catch(tf::TransformException& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
        return;
      }
      std::cout << "publishing" << std::endl;
      scan_pub.publish(cloud);
/*      tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
      tf::Transform transform;
      transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(0, 0, 0));
      transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1));
      br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "map", "odom_combined"));*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_scan_to_cloud");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  LaserScanToPointCloud lstopc(n);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

The code works fine when the tf frame that I pass to the Message Filter is the same as the laser's frame. But I have issues when I try to add transforms from the laser frame (not fixed) to a fixed frame. When I add this extra frame, the code will sporadically spit out a pointcloud, but no where near the consistency when I just use one frame.

I get this warning every time I run the code, if it's important:

```
[ WARN] [1376004701.242796255]: Message from [/hokuyo_node] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71914/non-fully-qualified-frame_id/) by [Challen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5350/challen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should add an "/" in front of the laser frame. In multi-robot systems you will likely have a namespace in front of the laser frame like "/robot_1/laser".

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Challen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5350/challen/) on 2013-08-09**:
Thanks. It looks like that's going to work.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-03**:
Could you please explain a bit more about the "/" ? Also, since it mentions "locally resolved" doesn't it solve the problem ? Thank you.